# How can I avoid connection timeout when the same php file runs multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, include, connection-timeout

Please I need your help with a `php` script I am trying to build.
I have created this script to send multiple sms to some recipients.All data are stored into a database table (data > 1500 rows).I use `select` query with `LIMIT 0, 1`. When the message goes I delete the specific row and I `include` the file again to proceed to the next `row`. The problem is that at the time the `rows` = 300 I have a CONNECTION TIMEOUT ERROR. Please let me know how can I solve this or if there is another way to figure this out..

Answer (score 1):

You need to change in your `php.ini` file these two lines based on your requiredment

```
 max_execution_time = 60;  // sec
```

Or Put this line at the top of your page

```
set_time_limit(100);   // Sec
```

Comment: Thanks but if I don't want to change `php.in` at all..What other options I have?

Comment: Change through your code by adding this line  `set_time_limit(20);`..refer manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

There is max_execution_time limit in php.ini file, the file will execute 30seconds (default execution time in php), so you can add this code in top of your file.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
```

here 600 means seconds.

Comment: I will try it..Is there another way to make execution time initialize again?Something like `shell_exec` instead of `include` which I use?

Comment: shell_exec is for executing linux commands in php. so in order to increase file execution time, you need to set time limit in particular file or else change in php.ini file..